# Iterate through js for loop similarly to nth-child(#n + #)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, css-selectors

Fairly straightforward question; I'm a bit new to JS and was surprised to be unable to find something in my searches.

Within these two for loops, I'm looping through item previews in a Woocommerce shop. Wordpress automatically adds "first" and "last" classes here to adjust margins for styling. I've got a bit of a hacky thing going here where I'm using upsells as a manual recommended products section.

As you'll see below, I'm trying to first wipe out all instances of those classes on every li, then add "last" classes to only some lis: those that work within the columns/ placement I have set up. I'm trying to do this within an if/then statement that checks for screen width. I wasn't having any luck utilizing two separate for loops within each statement, for reasons that are currently a bit over my head.

**What I'd like to do:** I'd like to automate the for loop to automatically go through every two (or every 3 in the else statement) elements in my upsellLi variable. With CSS you could do something like .upsell .li:nth-child(1n + 2);. I've tried upsellLi([1] + 2); here, but didn't have any luck.

Thank you so much for taking a look!

```
function columnChange(mobile) {
  if (mobile.matches) { // If media query matches variable below function
        //If screen size matches variable (is smaller than 1000px wide in our case), change upsell products to have 2 columns
        upsellCols.classList.remove('columns-3');
        upsellCols.classList.add('columns-2');
        
        //After that, reset first and last columns, then add .last class to 2nd and 4th items to adjust spacing. This assumes a maximum of two rows.
        for (var i = 0; i < upsellLi.length; i++ ) {
            upsellLi[i].classList.remove('first');
            upsellLi[i].classList.remove('last');
            upsellLi[1].classList.add('last');
            upsellLi[3].classList.add('last');
            upsellLi[5].classList.add('last');
            //repeat with 5, 7, etc within brackets to add support for more rows
        }
  } else { //If screen size is larger than 1000px, change upsell products to have 3 columns
        upsellCols.classList.remove('columns-2');
        upsellCols.classList.add('columns-3');
        
        //After that, reset first and last columns, then add .last class to 3rd and 6th items to adjust spacing. This assumes a maximum of two rows. The "i is already defined" error in Elementor is actually chill because we're only using one for loop at a time thanks to the if/then statement :)
        for (var i = 0; i < upsellLi.length; i++ ) {
            upsellLi[i].classList.remove('first');
            upsellLi[i].classList.remove('last');
            upsellLi[2].classList.add('last');
            upsellLi[5].classList.add('last');
            //repeat with 8, 11, etc within brackets to add support for more rows
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if `i` is `0` in the first loop iteration, and `[i+2]` and `[i+5]` access the 3rd and 6th element like you want - what value would `i` need to have in the _next_ loop iteration then, to now access the 8th and 11th element in the same place ...? `i+2` was "3rd", so what would i have to be now to mean "8th"? It would have to be `5` now. So don't increment your loop variable by 1 in each iteration, as the current `i++` does - but make that `i+=5` instead.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the suggestion and for your help, that would definitely work to add the ".last" classes where I need them. 

Unfortunately I also need to loop through every single item using the current i++ because of the different screen sizes - if someone loads the screen at desktop size, for example, then drags the window down below 1000px, I need it to reset and re-register which products get the "last" class. 

Any ideas on how I can do that within my if/else screen size checking statement?

Comment: You could wrap the part that is supposed to work on the 3rd/6th, then 8th/11th, and so on, into a condition that checks if the current value of `i` is divisible by 5, using the modulo operator: `if(i % 5 == 0) { ... }`

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! I was able to get that working by changing the 0 to either 1 or 2 (depending on the number of columns) to start the count in the right place. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Answer per @CBroe in the comments! Here's where I ended up to get this working:

```
function columnChange(mobile) {
  if (mobile.matches) { // If media query matches variable below function
        //If screen size matches variable (is smaller than 1000px wide in our case), change upsell products to have 2 columns
        upsellCols.classList.remove('columns-3');
        upsellCols.classList.add('columns-2');
        
        //After that, reset first and last columns, then add .last class to last product in each row
        for (var i = 0; i < upsellLi.length; i++ ) {
            upsellLi[i].classList.remove('first');
            upsellLi[i].classList.remove('last');
            //Add "last" class to every two instances of upsellLi - check if each iteration's number within the loop is divisible by 2. The 1 at the end offsets the count to start on the second iteration (since the count starts at 0)
            if(i % 2 === 1) {
                upsellLi[i].classList.add('last');
            }
        }
  } else { //If screen size is larger than 1000px, change upsell products to have 3 columns
        upsellCols.classList.remove('columns-2');
        upsellCols.classList.add('columns-3');
        
        //After that, reset first and last columns, then add .last class to last product in each row
        for (var i = 0; i < upsellLi.length; i++ ) {
            upsellLi[i].classList.remove('first');
            upsellLi[i].classList.remove('last');
            //Add "last" class to every 3 instances of upsellLi - check if each iteration's number within the loop is divisible by 3. The 2 at the end offsets the count to start on the third iteration (since the count starts at 0)
            if(i % 3 === 2) {
                upsellLi[i].classList.add('last');
            }
        }
    }
}
```